# awk how to extract other fields "if duplicates in fields" only if previous fields are the same and above zero

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, awk, duplicates

I am trying to look into rows with duplicates from specific fields(columns 1 & 4)in a tab de-limited file and extract specific columns from first and last row of duplicates fields block; only if the previous fields are the same and also values are above 0. For example:

if two columns ($1 and $4) are same at different location interspersed by others, need to treat them as separate blocks

Sample input:

```
  1  tmp1   153446387   153446446   -0.2    1.0888042
  2  tmp1   153446925   153446973   0   0.87891006
  3  tmp1   153451902   153451951   1.43854 1.2709045
  4  tmp1   153454056   153454105   1.43854 1.4132746
  5  tmp1   153456192   153456250   1.43854 0.87553155
  6  tmp1   153458717   153458776   1.335858    1.1829022
  7  tmp1   153460782   153460841   1.335858    0.006651476
  8  tmp1   153462035   153462094   0   0.13484457
  9  tmp1   153463690   153463749   1.43854 0.45511296
 10  tmp1   153467589   153467673   1.43854 1.4431274
 11  tmp1   153467873   153468632   0.31841 1.70443
 12  tmp1   154451904   154451951   1.43854 1.3709045
 13  tmp1   154454054   154454109   1.43854 1.132746
 14  tmp1   154456194   154456259   1.43854 0.8553
 15  tmp2   153472147   153472194   1.43854 0.99288875
 16  tmp2   153476511   153476559   0   0.99288875
```

Output:

```
tmp1    153451902   153456250   1.43854
tmp1    153458717   153460841   1.335858
tmp1    153463690   153467673   1.43854
tmp1    154451904   154456259   1.43854
tmp2    153472147   153472194   1.43854
```

Any ideas on how to go about this

Comment: Your requirements are not clear to me. Why, in the second block of lines with field1="tmp1" and field4="1.43854", do you want two lines to appear in the output? In this block of 6 lines, what happens after the 2nd line that makes you want to print a line of output? Please take a minute to clearly define the problem you're asking us to solve for you.

Comment: I have just added line number above to explain you in detail.

Comment: You didn't answer the question: what happens between lines 10 and 11?

Comment: my bad: i corrected the input now; my question is if in case those two columns (1 and 4 ) if have same values far part separated by other blocks ; i wanted them to be treated as separate blocks

Comment: So then why doesn't line 11 appear in your expected output? Its $4 is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS = FS = "\t"}
    function output(key, ary) {
        split(key, ary, FS)
        print ary[1], start, end, ary[2]
    }
    $4 <= 0 {next}
    key != $1 FS $4 {
        if (end) {output(key)}
        key = $1 FS $4
        start = $2
    }
    {end = $3}
    END {output(key)}
' filename
```

Comment: thanks alot; BTW how can i add number of number of lines in each block and also difference in final start and end?

Comment: @newbiee, in the "key != ..." block, initialize the count to 0, and in the "{end = $3}" block, increment the count. Then pass the count to the "output" function as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks it worked; I added to the print statement count, end-start;

Comment: what if two columns ($1 and $4) are same at different location? it is treating them as same block which iam not looking for?

Comment: Do we need any previous and current variables to be associated with the key? or print out immediately when it exists current block? I highly appreciate your inputs...thanks

Comment: Change the "$4 <= 0" block to `{if (end) {output(key)}; key = ""; next}`

Comment: Thanks you Glenn Jackmann; you are amazing. Script is almost there... I used `$4 <= 0 {if (end) {output(key)}; key = ""; next}`  Its printing extra output lines `153458717       153460841` and  `153472147       153472194`  : since my input file has millions of lines : it is printing that many times in between actual output lines....but i think i need to sort the output and delete those extra lines....